# Cannot execute learning task. : Unable to create retraining task - previous training data not present

Tags: ibm-watson, visual-recognition

I am trying to update a classifier. In zip folder, I have more than 10 images. But still, not able to update.

Tried via swagger URl: https://watson-api-explorer.ng.bluemix.net/apis/visual-recognition-v3#!/Custom/updateClassifier

URL:   `https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition/api/v3/classifiers/sports_cars_1042527461?version=2018-03-19&api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx`

CURL: `curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' --header 'Accept: application/json' {"type":"formData"} 'https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition/api/v3/classifiers/sports_cars_1042527461?version=2018-03-19&api_key=xxxxx'`

RESPONSE: `{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "error_id": "input_error",
    "description": "Cannot execute learning task.  : Unable to create retraining task - previous training data not present."
  }
}`

Tried it with `Node JS` code too but got the same error.

Is there anything I missed or tried something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

One thing I noticed is that you have a mix of URL and authentication for older and newer classifiers.

For classifiers created before May 23, you use the URL `gateway-a.` and `&api_key=...`.

For classifiers created afterward, you use the URL `gateway.` and IAM authentication (`-u "apikey:{apikey}"`).

so

```
curl -X POST \
-F "sportscars_positive_examples=@sc.zip" \
-F "negative_examples=@suvs.zip" \ 
"https://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition/api/v3/classifiers
    /sports_cars_1042527461?version=2018-03-19&api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

or

```
curl -X POST -u "apikey:yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy" \
-F "sportscars_positive_examples=@sc.zip" \
-F "negative_examples=@suvs.zip" \ 
"https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition/api/v3/classifiers
    /sports_cars_1042527461?version=2018-03-19"
```

For details, look at the [API reference](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/visual-recognition/api/v3/curl.html?curl#authentication).